# @ConditionalOnProperty for lists or arrays?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.3 `@AutoConfiguration` where I create beans automatically based on properties user specifies.  User can specify an array of services, where **name** and **version** are required fields:

```
service[0].name=myServiceA
service[0].version=1.0

service[1].name=myServiceB
service[1].version=1.2

...
```

If the user forgets to specify a required field on even just one service, I want to back-off and not create any beans.  Can I accomplish this with `@ConditionalOnProperty`? I want something like:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty({"service[i].name", "service[i].version"})
class AutoConfigureServices {
....
}
```

Comment: I don't *think* this is valid per se--but if you're setting those values in a constructor, you could get an exception thrown there (either explicitly in the constructor or implicitly if Spring checks for presence).

Comment: That's a good idea. If constructor gets run on an autoconfigure class before any beans are instantiated, maybe i could somehow prevent beans from being created? Unfortunately i can't throw exceptions cause forgetting the props shouldn't be fatal.

Comment: Why not? You have a half-configured bean.

Comment: Ya, if the bean's half configured at construction, then constructor won't work. `@Autoconfiguration` and `@Conditionals` prevent the beans from ever being created. The idea is the user depends on a jar with the autoconfigurations, but it shouldn't prevent their app from loading by throwing fatals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the custom `Condition` I created. It needs some polishing to be more generic (ie not hardcoding strings), but worked great for me.

To use, I annotated my Configuration class with `@Conditional(RequiredRepeatablePropertiesCondition.class)`

```
public class RequiredRepeatablePropertiesCondition extends SpringBootCondition {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequiredRepeatablePropertiesCondition.class.getName());

    public static final String[] REQUIRED_KEYS = {
            "my.services[i].version",
            "my.services[i].name"
    };

    @Override
    public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        List<String> missingProperties = new ArrayList<>();
        RelaxedPropertyResolver resolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(context.getEnvironment());
        Map<String, Object> services = resolver.getSubProperties("my.services");
        if (services.size() == 0) {
            missingProperties.addAll(Arrays.asList(REQUIRED_KEYS));
            return getConditionOutcome(missingProperties);
        }
        //gather indexes to check: [0], [1], [3], etc
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]");
        Set<String> uniqueIndexes = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String key : services.keySet()) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(key);
            if (m.find()) {
                uniqueIndexes.add(m.group(1));
            }
        }
        //loop each index and check required props
        uniqueIndexes.forEach(index -> {
            for (String genericKey : REQUIRED_KEYS) {
                String multiServiceKey = genericKey.replace("[i]", "[" + index + "]");
                if (!resolver.containsProperty(multiServiceKey)) {
                    missingProperties.add(multiServiceKey);
                }
            }
        });
        return getConditionOutcome(missingProperties);
    }

    private ConditionOutcome getConditionOutcome(List<String> missingProperties) {
        if (missingProperties.isEmpty()) {
            return ConditionOutcome.match(ConditionMessage.forCondition(RequiredRepeatablePropertiesCondition.class.getCanonicalName())
                    .found("property", "properties")
                    .items(Arrays.asList(REQUIRED_KEYS)));
        }
        return ConditionOutcome.noMatch(
                ConditionMessage.forCondition(RequiredRepeatablePropertiesCondition.class.getCanonicalName())
            .didNotFind("property", "properties")
            .items(missingProperties)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this code only works with Spring Boot 1.x, Spring Boot 2 replaced this code with different API see their [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#relaxed-binding).

`RelaxedPropertyResolver` in particular do not exists anymore, and there is no direct replacement for `RelaxedPropertyResolver.getSubProperties(...)` or [`PropertySourceUtils.getSubProperties(...)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11463).

Comment: @Brice is correct, and thanks for link for migration guide. I tried code from their example and this works for me:
    
```
Binder.get(context.getEnvironment()).bind("my.services", List.class).orElse(null);
```
that returns List<String>. I didn't try parsing into POJO (as AutoConfigureService), but helps for simple Strings

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyListCondition` class. For example, given you want to check for the `service` property having at least one value:

```
class MyListCondition extends OnPropertyListCondition {
    MyListCondition() {
        super("service", () -> ConditionMessage.forCondition("service"));
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@Condition(MyListCondition.class)
class AutoConfigureServices {

}
```

See the [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.OnWsdlLocationsCondition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.7/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/webservices/OnWsdlLocationsCondition.java) used on [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration#wsdlDefinitionBeanFactoryPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.7/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/webservices/WebServicesAutoConfiguration.java#L85) for an example within Spring itself.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I hope my answer will help for Spring2.x:
Thanks to @Brian, I checked migration guide, where I was inspired by example code. This code works for me:

```
final List<String> services = Binder.get(context.getEnvironment()).bind("my.services", List.class).orElse(null);
```

I did try to get List of POJO (as AutoConfigureService) but my class differs from AutoConfigureServices. For that purpose, I used:

```
final Services services = Binder.get(context.getEnvironment()).bind("my.services", Services.class).orElse(null);
```

Well, keep playing :-D

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this issue with the use of custom conditions in Spring autoconfiguration. Somewhat similar to what @Strumbels proposed but more reusable.

`@Conditional` annotations are executed very early in during the application startup. Properties sources are already loaded but ConfgurationProperties beans are not yet created. However we can work around that issue by binding properties to Java POJO ourselves.

First I introduce a functional interface which will enable us to define any custom logic checking if properties are in fact present or not. In your case this method will take care of checking if the property List is empty/null and if all items within are valid.

```java
public interface OptionalProperties {
  boolean isPresent();
}
```

Now let's create an annotation which will be metannotated with Spring `@Conditional` and allow us to define custom parameters. `prefix` represents the property namespace and `targetClass` represents the configuration properties model class to which properties should be mapped.

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Conditional(OnConfigurationPropertiesCondition.class)
public @interface ConditionalOnConfigurationProperties {

  String prefix();

  Class<? extends OptionalProperties> targetClass();

}
```

And now the main part. The custom condition implementation.

```java
public class OnConfigurationPropertiesCondition extends SpringBootCondition {

  @Override
  public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    MergedAnnotation<ConditionalOnConfigurationProperties> mergedAnnotation = metadata.getAnnotations().get(ConditionalOnConfigurationProperties.class);
    String prefix = mergedAnnotation.getString("prefix");
    Class<?> targetClass = mergedAnnotation.getClass("targetClass");
    // type precondition
    if (!OptionalProperties.class.isAssignableFrom(targetClass)) {
      return ConditionOutcome.noMatch("Target type does not implement the OptionalProperties interface.");
    }
    // the crux of this solution, binding properties to Java POJO
    Object bean = Binder.get(context.getEnvironment()).bind(prefix, targetClass).orElse(null);
    // if properties are not present at all return no match
    if (bean == null) {
      return ConditionOutcome.noMatch("Binding properties to target type resulted in null value.");
    }
    OptionalProperties props = (OptionalProperties) bean;

    // execute method from OptionalProperties interface 
    // to check if condition should be matched or not
    // can include any custom logic using property values in a type safe manner
    if (props.isPresent()) {
      return ConditionOutcome.match();
    } else {
      return ConditionOutcome.noMatch("Properties are not present.");
    }
  }

}
```

Now you should create your own configuration properties class implementing `OptionalProperties` interface.

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("your.property.prefix")
@ConstructorBinding
public class YourConfigurationProperties implements OptionalProperties {

  // Service is your POJO representing the name and version subproperties
  private final List<Service> services;

  @Override
  public boolean isPresent() {
    return services != null && services.stream().all(Service::isValid);
  }

}
```

And then in Spring `@Configuration` class.

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnConfigurationProperties(prefix = "", targetClass = YourConfigurationProperties.class)
class AutoConfigureServices {
....
}
```

There are two downsides to this solution:

- Property prefix must be specified in two locations: on `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation and on `@ConditionalOnConfigurationProperties` annotation. This can partially be alleviated by defining a `public static final String PREFIX = "namespace"` in your configuration properties POJO.
- Property binding process is executed separately for each use of our custom conditional annotation and then once again to create the configuration properties bean itself. It happens only during app startup so it shouldn't be an issue but it still is an inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, your problem its how to validate mandatory fields, for it my suggestion will be use a @ConfigurationProperties("root") annotation, and then add all fields as @NotNull like this:

```
@Getter
@Validated
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties("root")
public class YourProperties {

  private final Set<Item> service;

  @Getter
  @Validated
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  public static class Item {

    @NotNull
    private final String name;

    @NotNull
    private final String version;
  }
}
```

In case you prefer continue with conditional approach you could use ConditionalOnExpression, however, should be aware that number of items its unlimited:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils).hasText('${service[0].name}')}")
```